# Delete commit git

Tags: git, git-rebase

I somehow did this:

```
A -- B -- C (init)
         /
        Z   (master)
```

I can't figure out how to delete the Z commit or ho to "rebase" it as a parent of A. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothing of use in Z you can get rid of it with `reset --hard`

```
git reset --hard init (if init is a branch)
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD^ (moves one commit back)
```

If you need to keep Z but as early as possible (first possible is after A) then you can do an interactiv rebase

```
git rebase -i <sha of A>
```

and reorder de commits as

```
Z
B
C
```

(A is not show as it's the root commit)

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to delete it? Just revert that commit.

```
git revert <SHA-ID>
```

Or else, You want to nuke commit. The hard reset to `HEAD-1` will set your working copy to the state of the commit before your wrong commit.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: The commit is 'useless' only file in here is empty .gitignore. Commit A has already initialized .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

To make Z commit as the parent of A try this:

```
git checkout -b b_branch {B hash}
git checkout master
git rebase b_branch
git checkout -b a_branch {A hash}
git rebase master
```

Comment: this just ff master ref from Z to the commit C. The commit Z is still in my graph :(

Comment: @svobol13 I've updated my post, now it describes how to insert Z commit between B and A